# How do I connect CustomAuthenticationProvider to frontend?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, authentication, basic-authentication

I'm doing a project with SpringBoot backend, Vue.js frontend and H2 database. I'm trying to implement authentication with CustomAuthenticationProvider. I'm able to authenticate a user stored in my database when entering the port for the backend. (A login pops up.) But this is on the backend. My frontend will be on a diffrent port. How do I connect it frontend?

I suppose if I knew how to "login" from sending information from Postman, I would be able to figure out how to make the method. But I don't know how and only get 401 unauthorised feedback. Should I be sending some HTTPS? It's supposed to https basic auth.

[image: login pop-up]
(It says login, username, password, login, cancel.)

```
import java.util.Collection;
import ntnu.krod.springBackend.repo.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import ntnu.krod.springBackend.model.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = null;

        // Get username and password from request
        final String username = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (user != null) {
            if (username.equals(user.getUsername()) && password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")); //TODO Consider admin role
                authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, grantedAuthorities), password, grantedAuthorities);

            }
        }
        else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + username + " not found.");
        }

        return authenticationToken;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# default path: h2-console
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-ui

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./H/h2db/testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

#Added for security
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/demo
```

Please let me know if I need to include more information!

Answer (score 0):

In Postman you can provide Basic Auth from Authorization tab. There you can add username and password and access the url without a popup coming up.

[image: Postman Authorization1]

From your Front End App you need to send an Authorization header.

```
Authorization: Basic base64Encode(username+":"+password)
```

`base64Encode` is the encode function so that you can convert your `testusername:testpassword` to an encoded value and will have something like below.

```
Authorization: Basic ehdro389erje34903==
```

Comment: What class do I import to create a Basic object?